# PhpStorm: заменить комментарий, который вставляется при создании файлов

Tags: phpstorm, php

Приветствую. Подскажите, где можно изменить комментарий в phpStorm, который вставляется при создании файлов, т.е.

```
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: User
 * Date: 29.08.14
 * Time: 1:48
 */
```

Comment: ide settings - file templates (шторма под рукой нет, название секции может немного отличаться).

Answer (score 3):

[[@Etki](/users/16095/etki)](/users/16095/etki) прав, немного уточню (версия 7.1.4): 
Preferences -> File and Code Templates (в разделе IDE Settings) -> для смены надписи в php файлах нужно выбрать вкладку includes